# Parsing XML using python using xmldom or etree

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML in the below format:

```
<root>
    <child>
        <param1> 1 </param1>
        <param2> 2 </param2>
    </child>

    <other_child>
        <grand_child>
            <param>a</param>
            <param>b</param>
        </grand_child>
        <grand_child2>
            <param>c</param>
            <param>d</param>
        </grand_child2>
    </other_child>
</root>
```

I have been using the below code snippets to parse it.

```
root = eTree.parse(configFile).getroot()

for child in root:
    for g_child in child:
        print(g_child.tag, g_child.attrib)
```

This is the output I get:

```
param1 {}
param2 {}
grand_child {}
grand_child2 {}
```

I also tried `minidom` and it gives me similar results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It returns a correct result.

Comment: Can you post your output? Thanks.

Comment: What result did you expect? I didn't run your code but my response above is based on your code and your output. Edit: I get the same output.

Comment: I expect 
`param1 1
param2 2
`
etc..

Comment: In this case you should be using `g_child.text` instead of `g_child.attrib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the values of the `params` you can do something like:

```
for child in root:
    for g_child in child:
        print(g_child.text)
        for g in g_child:
            print(g.text)
```

This was my output (Notice the spaces)

```
1 
2 


a
b


c
d
```